# Plot time series from data frame

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I'm trying to plot a time series from a data frame in this format:

```
Gene    t1  t2  t3      t4  t5
geneA   0.171708555542224   0.767412947810676   0.754849467082325   0.893904836629662   -0.451533145139049
geneB   0.32989453548287    0.304464261184109   0.632407796520215   1.2965570364275 -0.00269630000204213
geneC   1.47092503615513    0.708756145675017   1.27888805232732    1.45653164709635    0.913461102204938
geneD   0.379307974619187   0.577591822285932   -0.203915993729493  0.0743865362148819  0.561894770555292
geneE   -0.162029544343246  0.332622377925421   1.18614452957358    1.87262670303989    0.100212594882377
CG10170-RA  -0.152808420012908  -0.294930227688068  0.935190065253332   1.98475948430149    0.282560916666689
```

For each gene (rows) I'd like to have a line representing the expression value at the 5 different time points (columns).

It should be fairly trivial but I couldn't find a way so far... what's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: The option `type="l"` in the `plot` function should do the trick. If all lines should be plotted in the same plot you could plot the first one like this and add the following ones with the `lines` command. And for `x` you take then the timepoints or e.g. `1:5`.

Comment: Can you please write it down as code? What I'm trying doesn't really work.

Comment: I believe that G.Grothendieck's answer is the nicer approach compared to my suggestions, but if you want to use the `plot` function and assuming that you have your data in a matrix called `genes`, just type `plot(1:5,genes[1,],type="l")` and additional lines then with `lines(1:5,genes[2,])` etc (maybe in a loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `DF` is the data frame first put it in a more standard form where each column is a time series.  Then use `matplot` :

```
m <- setNames(t(DF[-1]), DF[[1]])
n <- nrow(m)
matplot(1:n, m)
```

or using zoo we can plot it using classic graphics, lattice graphics or ggplot2 graphics using a single or multiple panel for each:

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(m)

# classic graphics
plot(z) # multiple panels
plot(z, screens = 1, col = 1:n) # one panel

library(lattice)
xyplot(z)
xyplot(z, screens = 1, col = 1:n)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z)
autoplot(z, facets = NULL) + aes(linetype = NULL)
```